# How do you connect SwiftUI app commands to functions within other views?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

The new SwiftUI app declaration introduced at WWDC20 allows the implementation of app commands which appear in the menu bar.  How should these be connected to their respective function in subviews?

### Sample Code

```
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
                Button("Do something", action: {
                    // Call the function in SubView
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    var body: some View { ... }
    
    func doSomething() {
        
    }
}
```

Ideas which I had thought of include:

- NotificationCenter
- Combine publishers
- EnvironmentObjects

What is the best practice to achieve this?
Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’m guessing you connect these with .onCommand, which is based on the Mac responder chain, but it uses selectors so I’m not sure how you use it with CommandGroup… https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group/oncommand(_:perform:)

Comment: "Best practice"-type question aren't very suitable for StackOverflow because they lead to opinion-based answers. It also depends on what you're optimizing for in your use case. For example, do you have a loosely coupled app? (Then either a NotificationCenter or a combine publisher on an environment object could be the way to go). Do you have tight coupling? Then a delegation pattern could be the way to go (i.e. a view model subscribes itself as a delegator)

Comment: Did you find a way (or workaround) to connect the function to the command?